# Windows can't reach IP host through two routes

Tags: windows, networking, ip, routing

Problem: Windows 10 can't reach an IP host behind two routers, where the path is specified in static routes.

Windows has the following setup:

```
Windows Host (192.168.3.1/24 for the local LAN with default gw 192.168.3.254 and
              10.0.0.101/28  for the VPN to the secured systems) ->
VPN Router (10.0.0.97 - IP on Windows host's end) ->
Security Router (10.212.69.3 - behind VPN endpoint) ->
Target host (100.102.1.136 - somewhere behind Security Router)
```

I have the following static routes defined on the Windows host:

```
           IP          Netmask          Gateway    Metric
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.3.254  Standard
  100.102.0.0      255.254.0.0      10.212.69.3         1 <<- Target network
  10.212.69.3  255.255.255.255        10.0.0.97         2 <<- Security Router behind VPN
```

When I ping the target host 100.102.1.136 I would expect the IP package to go from the Windows host to the VPN router, through the VPN tunnel, to the Security router and from there to the target network. It does, however, go directly to the default gateway of the Windows network (192.168.3.254), where - of course - it can't be processed.

I can ping the Security Router (10.212.69.3), so that is working fine, but Windows is chosing the wrong path for the target behind the Security Router

```
C:\>tracert 100.102.3.136

Routenverfolgung zu 100.102.3.136 über maximal 30 Hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  fritz.box [192.168.3.254]
  2  p4fabf621.dip0.t-ipconnect.de [62.155.246.33]  meldet: Zielnetz nicht erreichbar.

C:\>tracert 10.212.69.3

Routenverfolgung zu 10.212.69.3 über maximal 30 Hops

  1     8 ms     7 ms     8 ms  10.0.0.97
  2     9 ms     8 ms     8 ms  10.212.69.3
```

What am I missing?

Edit: As requested, this is the route print and ipconfig output

```
IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.3.254       10.0.0.101    281
        10.0.0.96  255.255.255.240   Auf Verbindung        10.0.0.101    281
       10.0.0.101  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung        10.0.0.101    281
       10.0.0.111  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung        10.0.0.101    281
      10.212.69.3  255.255.255.255        10.0.0.97       10.0.0.101     27
      100.102.0.0      255.254.0.0      10.212.69.3       10.0.0.101     26
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
      188.144.0.0      255.254.0.0      10.212.69.3       10.0.0.101     26
      192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung        10.0.0.101    281
      192.168.3.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung        10.0.0.101    281
    192.168.3.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung        10.0.0.101    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung        10.0.0.101    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung        10.0.0.101    281
===========================================================================
St„ndige Routen:
  Netzwerkadresse          Netzmaske  Gatewayadresse  Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.3.254  Standard 
      100.102.0.0      255.254.0.0      10.212.69.3       1
      10.212.69.3  255.255.255.255        10.0.0.97       2
===========================================================================


Windows-IP-Konfiguration

   Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-Routing aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein
   WINS-Proxy aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein

Ethernet-Adapter LAN1:

   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) I210 Gigabit Network Connection #2
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.101(Bevorzugt) 
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.1(Bevorzugt) 
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.3.254
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the full output of `ipconfig` and `route print`. (You can remove the output for interfaces that don't have an IP address.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer on [another platform](https://serverfault.com/questions/1145037/windows-cant-reach-ip-host-through-two-routes/1145040#1145040):

Routers route based on their routing table, not the routing table of the client. You can only specify next hop, you can't instruct upstream routers what to do.

Thus your route should be `100.102.1.136 via 10.0.0.97.`